# Clarify if new DS-160 is needed if change venue from London to Belfast after transmitting

Tags: visas, usa, london

On the Belfast FAQs PDF (https://photos.state.gov/libraries/unitedkingdom/164203/pdf/Belfast-FAQs-2015.pdf) it says:

> I selected "England, London" as the processing location on my DS-160
>   visa application form but I want to apply/I have already booked an
>   appointment in Belfast.  Is this a problem?

This is the situation I am in and I have already booked an appointment in Belfast.  The answer to this FAQ confuses me because the first paragraph says:

> You should complete a new DS-160 selecting "Northern Ireland, Belfast"
>   as the processing location at least 24 hours before your Belfast
>   interview.

However, if you look at the US VISA Site (https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html) it says:

> What happens to my DS-160 if I select a U.S. Embassy or Consulate
>   where I will be applying for my visa, but end up making an interview
>   appointment instead at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate?
>
> The Embassy or Consulate at which you actually apply should be able to
>   access your form using the barcode on your DS-160 confirmation page,
>   which you must bring to the visa interview. For example, a business
>   traveler intends to apply for his visa at the U.S. Embassy in City X,
>   so he selects City X as the location where he will submit his
>   application when he completes his DS-160. He then has an urgent reason
>   to travel to City Y on business. Because there is a U.S. Consulate in
>   City Y, he schedules an appointment for a visa interview there, using
>   the barcode from his completed DS-160 application for appointment
>   scheduling. The U.S. Consulate in City Y is able to accept his DS-160
>   even though it lists the U.S. Embassy in City X as the location where
>   he originally intended to submit his application.

The Belfast FAQ question site then goes on to say:

> If you have already created an account and/or booked a Belfast
>   appointment with a London DS160, you do not need to change the DS160
>   number on your account at https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-gb/niv as it
>   does not change your application in any way.

I am confused now.  Do I need to do a new DS160 if I did a DS160 selecting "London, England", but subsequently chose an appointment in "Northern Ireland, Belfast", or not?  My Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application (DS-160) Confirmation" shows location selected = LND.

What's that second bit from the Belfast FAQ mean?  Is "change the DS160 number on your account" the same thing as completing a new DS160?  What does it mean to change the number?

Comment: I still got contradictory information because I called the helpline once again and they told me to do a new DS-160 and book a new appointment.  But then I pointed out that the FAQ on travel.state.gov seemed to say the opposite. They then said to do whatever travel.state.gov FAQ told me to do. I've printed out the FAQ to take to the interview to show them. With timings now it it better to at least try in Belfast.

Comment: I just wanted to follow-up since I have a similar question: did this work?